# Batch: Preserve (creation-)date on copying files to another (flatten) folder structure, incl. renaming files to avoid doublettes

Tags: batch-file, copy, robocopy, file-attributes

this is my first question, so I apologize beforehand if I write not as you are used to...

#### fact:

I've a deep folder structure with tons of files (images,videos and so on) so I want to copy that files to a flat structure for a better overview.
I want to keep (at least) the original date attributes: creation-date and last-modified date.

**Problem 1**) there are files with same name 00001.jpg in different folders which I want to have in same folder, so I want to add creation date/time to filename on copy process.

`00001.jpg` becomes `2015-11-17_11-23-35_00001.jpg`

So far so good. Or not good...

`Copy` and `XCopy` doesn't give me an option to do that, without loosing at least the creation date information (I didn`t find a solution with both).

Now I try to copy the files (file by file) with `robocopy` to new folder and use `ren` on the copied file to "pre-set" the date/time information before the filename.

Here is a simple `test.bat` example:

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

robocopy . ./zzz original.txt /copy:DATSO
pause

rem :: formatted creation date of original file will be here, in real life
set "myDate=2015-11-17-_11-23-35"

rem rename "./zzz/original.txt" "!myDate!_renamed.txt" ::doesnt work: why? relative path??

rem :: this will do what I want - original creation date is kept on copy file
FOR %%A IN (zzz/original.txt) DO REN "%%~fA" "!myDate!_%%~nxA"
```

*[possibly]* **Problem2**) Is there a better way to do this, or could I run into thread problems (asynchronous execution). Could it be, that I try to rename a file before the robocopy has finished the copy process (e.g. for large files)?

Sorry I'm a totally batch newbie (also as poster in SO ;).

ThanX in advance for each tip and also for critics on my solution approach. Maybe I have the horse-blinkers on my head and dont see the easy solution?!

1. [edit: formatting of post]
2. [edit: content of post -> date/time in front of filename for better sorting]

Comment: `rem rename "./zzz/original.txt" "!myDate!_renamed.txt"` does not rename the file because the command __REM__ remarks this line as comment line. Remove `rem` from this line and it should work as expected. The directory separator on Windows is ``\`` and not `/`. Correct this in your batch file. And ``.\`` means current directory which can be omitted completely and use only "zzz\original.txt" to rename the file in subdirectory `zzz`. And the file creation date is the date a file was created the first time in current directory and not when the file content was written the first time into a file.

Comment: Hi, yes I know about ´rem´ ... its commented out in example, because it doen't work. This was wanted, not a mistake.

Comment: btw.: I didn't want to start a principled discussion about, when I should modify file date attributes an when not ;) I want to know is it possible to do it with other tools in an acceptable way for bulks of files.

Comment: ´./´ or ´.\´ is the relative path, I know, therefore the question why it doesn't work (see comment at end of line). I'll try your proposal to omit this completely. The reason for the main question was, how to preserve the creation date of the original on copying this (without any changes) to a new folder structure! I want to preserve that date for many resons. e.g. file-name can change over the time multiple times, but in a few years I want to know, when the file was created, not when was it copied! ThanX for your answer, but it doesnt really help for that problem!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use command **DIR** to get recursive listed all files in the specified folder and its subfolders with creation date/time.

The format of the date/time depends on **Windows Region and Language** settings.

Example output for `F:\Temp\Test` on my machine with English Windows 7 and region is configured to Germany on running the command line `dir F:\Temp\Test\* /A-D /S /TC`:

```
 Volume in drive F is TEMP
 Volume Serial Number is 1911-26A4

 Directory of F:\Temp\Test

25.09.2017  17:26           465.950 SimpleFile.ccl
               1 File(s)        465.950 bytes

 Directory of F:\Temp\Test\Test Folder

25.09.2017  17:26           360.546 Test File.tmp
               1 File(s)        360.546 bytes

     Total Files Listed:
               2 File(s)        826.496 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  58.279.460.864 bytes free
```

This output is filtered with `findstr /R /C:"^ Directory of" /C:"^[0123][0123456789]"` to get only lines starting with  `Directory of` (note the space at begin) or with a number in range `00` to `39`.

```
 Directory of F:\Temp\Test
25.09.2017  17:26           465.950 SimpleFile.ccl
 Directory of F:\Temp\Test\Test Folder
25.09.2017  17:26           360.546 Test File.tmp
```

And this filtered output is processed by **FOR** loop and the commands executed by **FOR**.

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=1-2*" %%A in ('dir "F:\Temp\Test\*" /A-D /S /TC ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R /C:"^ Directory of" /C:"^[0123][0123456789]" 2^>nul') do (
    if "%%A %%B" == "Directory of" (
        set "FilePath=%%C"
    ) else (
        set "CreationDate=%%A"
        set "CreationTime=%%B"
        for /F "tokens=1*" %%I in ("%%C") do set "FileName=%%J"
        call :RenameFile
    )
)
goto :EOF

:RenameFile
set "NewName=%CreationDate:~-4%-%CreationDate:~3,2%-%CreationDate:~0,2%_%CreationTime:~0,2%-%CreationTime:~3,2%_%FileName%"
ren "%FilePath%\%FileName%" "%NewName%"
goto :EOF
```

It would be advisable to put command `echo` before command `ren` in last but one line to first verify the expected new file names.

```
ren "F:\Temp\Test\SimpleFile.ccl" "2017-09-25_17-26_SimpleFile.ccl"
ren "F:\Temp\Test\Test Folder\Test File.tmp" "2017-09-25_17-26_Test File.tmp"
```

**Note:** The batch file must be in a folder not processed by this batch file as otherwise the batch file itself would be renamed while running which breaks the processing of the batch file.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `ren /?`
- `set /?`

By the way: **WinRAR** can add files into a RAR archive with creation and last access time in addition to last modification time and extract the files to a different directory with restoring also creation and last access time using [SetFileTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724933.aspx) function of Windows kernel.

Answer (score 0):

currently I use Locale independent date. I use tokens from that for currrent date/time.

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('wmic os get localdatetime /format:list') do set datetime=%%I
rem :: format it to YYYY-MM-DD_hh-mm-ss
set myDateTime=%datetime:~0,4%-%datetime:~4,2%-%datetime:~6,2%_%datetime:~8,2%-%datetime:~10,2%-%datetime:~12,2%
```

Thats not the problem.

To clarify: 
The listing is also not the problem. 
I loop throw all related files without a prob *(except batch files and output dir and its sub tree ;)*.

My problem is:

**I call robocopy for each file**, then I rename the file to save the original creation date. My fear is that it makes problems (Multi-Threading?) for large files and for the number of calls (many thousend times)

Is batch execution really serialized? Is the process waiting for robocopy, that it has finished, before I try to rename file. Could I run into dead-locks for vry large files? I'll test it with some fake gigabyte-files.

Your suggestion, **to use winrar** sounds interesting. 
If I could add all that files to a big archive (with structure) and at the end extract it to target dir... I'll try it ;)

If it doesn't work I will program it in java! 
There I know what to do, thats my playground :D

I thought it would be easy to write a simple batch file, to do this for me, *but it seems it's not as easy as I thought*!

**ThanX anyway**